# How can I send attachments using iphone mail-core api?

Tags: ios4, email-attachments, mailcore

I'm working on a project in which I'm using the mail-core iphone api to send and retrieve mail. I have tried a lot of things, but have been unable to find any solution.  I've tried searching but haven't found any solution. Could someone explain how to use the mail-core api to send attachments?. If anybody knows how to do that please let me know.

Comment: If you have multiple questions you should probably try ask them as different questions.  Also, it is much easier for people to help when questions are more specific as to what you have already tried as well as what errors/troubles you are experiencing with your attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this but if you look at the header for [`CTCoreMessage`](http://libmailcore.com/api/Classes/CTCoreMessage.html), it does have a method `addAttachment:`. Argument for this is a [`CTCoreAttachment`](http://libmailcore.com/api/Classes/CTCoreAttachment.html) object.

Comment: what is your personal mail id? I would like to talk with you. I'm also in hyderabad.

Comment: I look into the header but addAttachment is empty.

Comment: @Deepak Danduprolu changed the links to the proper links.

Answer (score 1):

Add this only and only after you setBody or setHTMLBody:

```
// Set Attachments
NSString *filePrefix = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",filePrefix,@"TestData/DSC_6201.jpg"];
NSLog(@"path:%@", path);

CTCoreAttachment *attach = [[CTCoreAttachment alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
if ([attach data]==nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error: attachment data is nil");
}
[myMessage addAttachment:attach];
```

Here, you should add TestData folder with image to your project as a folder reference